# Given that $\forall xQ(x)$ is true, is $\exists xQ(x)$ also true?

Tags: predicate-logic

> Given that $\forall xQ(x)$ is true, is $\exists xQ(x)$ also true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends what the domain of discourse is. If the set to which the $x$ may belong is empty, then $\forall x \ Q(x)$ can be true while $\exists x \ Q(x)$ is not true.

Comment: It also depends on the exact formulation of first-order logic: some *require* a non-empty domain of discourse, while other formulations allow an empty domain of discourse.  (And then, if the first-order logic *language* you're considering includes a nullary function symbol, or in other words a constant symbol, that always means that the domain of discourse is necessarily nonempty in any model.)

Comment: No, it is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes—as long as the set that the universal quantifier $\forall$ is ranging over is nonempty. For exmaple, $\forall x\in[0,1]\ Q(x)$ does imply $\exists x\in[0,1]\ Q(x)$, but $\forall x\in\emptyset\ Q(x)$ does not imply $\exists x\in\emptyset\ Q(x)$.

Comment: Hence it is not necessarily true.  Thanks for verifying that, in general, the proposition is not true.